# html onchange event not working after form submit. Ajax/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a testing form that is not working quite how I thought. We have two versions one with all questions on one page and one that is timed and you get one question at a time via ajax.  i have cookies being created to store questions and test progress so the users can come back to it later. this works fine on the static test but the timed one is having issues.  I have an onchange event that updates the cookie but the problem I have is on the timed one that only on the first question or if the page is refreshed does it have the onchange event, if i just submit answer and new question appears it does not have the event for some reason.  Hoping someone more familiar with ajax can point out what is wrong.

here is the code:

```
//Submits individual simulation exam questions and loads the next one.
function submitSimulation () {
    $('input:radio').removeAttr('disabled');
    var params = $('form').serialize();
    $('#spinner').show();
    $.ajax({
      url: "simulation.php",
      data: params,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data){
        $('#simexam').fadeOut(400, function(){$('#simexam').html(data).fadeIn(400);});
      }
    });
}
```

here is what the questions look like"

```
<input id="q{$question.question_id}answer4" type="radio" value="4" name="answer[{$question.question_id}]" onchange="cookieupdate('q{$question.question_id}answer4')"/>
```

this is the button code

```
<input type="button" name="next_question" class="submit" value="Next Question" onclick="submitSimulation();" /><img src="images/spinner.gif" style="display:none;position:relative;top:3px;left:3px;" id="spinner"/><br class="clear" />
```

this is what the next question looks like after the submit:

```
<input id="q{$question.question_id}answer4" type="radio" value="2" name="answer[{$question.question_id}]">
```

Comment: Is the html getting loaded in overwriting the html that had the listeners attached to it?

Comment: The only html code for the questions has the onchange event. but for some reason after submit it takes that part out

Comment: Well turns out i'm just an idiot.  Part of the form was calling an old testing file. Forgot to update it when i starting testing this new feature. Thanks!

Comment: Delete the question if it's no longer meaningful.